# nodejs file uploaded but server terminate and restart it self

Tags: node.js, azure, virtual-machine, fs, pm2

i have an azure virtual machine and there is a nodejs app within it, 
i did standard procedure for upload file using`fs` module, and with `multer` module, but there are some errors while uploading file , the file is uploaded but the server restarts it self , below are the log :

[image]

the code :

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, config.uploadDir);
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    const mime = file.mimetype.split(`/`);
    const type = mime[1];
    cb(null, `upload-${Date.now()}.${type}`);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
```

i'm using multer as middleware on route.

```
router.post(`/testUpload`, upload.single(`testUpload`), OrderController.testUpload);
```

Comment: Is there any error trace? Any logs...?

Comment: Sounds like a crash/restart of the node process. But no logs in sight.